# Im getting this error while taking the build in the xcode - React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

Undefined symbol: _SLDashboardSessionURLChangedNotification

Im getting this error while taking the build in the xcode - React Native [Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3jEj.png)

Im getting this error while build an app using xode for ios app.

Does anybody faced this issue while taking the build in ios

I have searched for the solution but couldn't find it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.